# Adding simple xor encryption in ffplay

Tags: c, encryption, ffmpeg

Looking at ffplay.c (https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffplay.c) and wanting to support some basic encryption, which lines of code are the most relevant?

To keep it simple- assume we are using a basic XOR cipher key that matches, in length, the video data.

In other words- where is the data actually read and return the bytes (so that we can modify it before bytes are returned)? :)

Comment: Can you detail a bit what you're trying to protect and in what scenario (data at rest, data in transit)?

Comment: For starters, data at rest (file on filesystem). Let's just assume for the time being that the entire file was encrypted by xoring the bytes, and now I want to get them back to play (via same xor). I'm looking at some other code out there like http://129.97.134.72:8888/h264dec.c which seems simpler and I think basically just passes a pointer in memory to a function av_parser_parse2(), but I don't see that happening in ffplay.c linked above

Comment: That's part of the decoder and I don't think you want to go there :) In your case you may be able to create a [custom IO context](http://miphol.com/muse/2014/03/custom-io-with-ffmpeg.html) to decrypt the  content and fill the player's input buffer.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably much more what I need- much appreciated!

Comment: As a followup- would you say ffplay is the best bare-bones way to get started playing h264/aac? I don't need all the user-settable options, goal is ultimately just to make a player with subtitles, seeking, and play/pause (controls will be in SDL too, I guess).

Comment: Yes, I would too start with `ffplay.c` for a standalone player.

Comment: Added the answer for posterity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using a custom [I/O context](http://miphol.com/muse/2014/03/custom-io-with-ffmpeg.html) using your own callbacks/buffers:

```
MyIOContext *ioCtx = new MyIOContext("random_file");
AVFormatContext *avFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
ioCtx->initAVFormatContext(avFormatCtx);
if (avformat_open_input(&avFormatCtx, "", NULL, NULL) != 0) {
    // handle error
}
// ...
avformat_close_input(&avFormatCtx);
```

Example read function from the [same source](https://gist.github.com/xlphs/9895065):

```
static int IOReadFunc(void *data, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size) {
    MyIOContext *hctx = (MyIOContext*)data;
    size_t len = fread(buf, 1, buf_size, hctx->fh);
    if (len == 0) {
        // Let FFmpeg know that we have reached EOF, or do something else
        return AVERROR_EOF;
    }
    return (int)len;
}
```

And the allocation:

```
// allocate the AVIOContext
ioCtx = avio_alloc_context(
    buffer, bufferSize, // internal buffer and its size
    0,            // write flag (1=true,0=false) 
    (void*)this,  // user data, will be passed to our callback functions
    IOReadFunc, 
    0,            // no writing
    IOSeekFunc
);
```